# Retrieve Criteria1 values of filtered data based on Date

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a worksheet filtered based on several criteria, one of which is based on date( I want the dates in 2018 for example)

I have found various routines such as the following:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-7564.html

However, whenever the loop goes to the column with the date criteria, the code crashes on the following line:

```
sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & sField & oFlt.Criteria1
```

Do you have any idea how I can retrieve the criteria based on a date?

Regards

Thanasis

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this before the line with the error:

```
MsgBox CDate(oFlt.Criteria1)
sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & sField & oFlt.Criteria1
```

Then try to work it out until you manage to get it through. Probably the `Criteria1` cannot be converted as a date or similar.